# Adding multiple data to one entity in Has Many and belongs to relationship

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on a form, where I have one user who can select main category and sub categories. But I want him to able to select multiple main category and sub categories.

I have setup to select main category where he can select multiple categories. But sub categories is different table and I want give him option to select sub categories with respect of main categories, I could not understand how can I manage it.

Current I am doing following and it is working fine.

my user.rb modle

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

my category.rb model

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

I have created migration to create join table

```
class CreateJoinTableUsersCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :categories do |t|
      t.index [:user_id, :category_id]
      t.index [:category_id, :user_id]
    end
  end
end
```

In my controller

```
    @categories = Category.find(params[:expertise])
    @user.categories << @categories
```

It all work fine, but I am confused how to add sub categories and then how to give option to select main categories to subcategories individual. I am thinking for following solutions.

1. I use big combo jquery box where I can select main and sub categories and than save it
2. I use two combos so first one is main categories and it populate sub categories, but I have to populate all main categories sub categories.

Any idea how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

As described here, what you need is self referential association. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories, class_name: "Category",
                          foreign_key: "parent_id"

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category", optional: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And here is the migration:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.references :parent
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You can now do:

```
a = Category.create(name: "Animal")
b = Category.create(name: "Dog")

a.subcategories << b
a.save
```